# How to check if current logged in user is in Firebase Database .child(Group)? Using Xamarin Android, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database, Parents and Babysitters]

I want to check if the current logged in user is either a babysitter or a parent, i have been trying it this way but i keep getting false.

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
var userType = firebase.Child("parent").Child("isAParent")
    .Equals(true);
```

Any help would be great thanks. I am using Xamarin Android, Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Your code is not reading anything from the Firebase Database yet. I'd recommend looking at the documentation of the library you're using to see how to perform queries. For example, this looks promising: https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin#querying

Comment: Thanks Frank, i only need to check to see if isAParent is True then all parents will be displayed in my listbox, if not true then All babysitters will be displayed. Im not sure how to use an If statement here rather than a for each in the link you gave me.

Comment: If you execute a query (which in the link happens in `.OnceAsync<YourObject>()`), there may be multiple matching child nodes. Even if in your app there is always only one result, the API doesn't know that, so you will always have to loop. But the most important right now is that you're not reading any data, so the query isn't even executed to begin with. My advice: first try reading all data as shown in the docs, then turn it into a query.